# Orcad hierarchical design alias / physical net

Tags: layout, orcad

A hierarchical based Orcad schemactic has two children blocks and the parent one. Each child block is connected through the parent via the net called VDD_IN. However, once I hover on the net, a physical net number is shown alongside the alias I attributed to it. What is bugging me is that in Orcad PCB, only the physical net is showing up after reading out the netlist. Is there a way of forcing the alias to be used in the Orcad PCB?

Here are the relevant part of each child block:

[image: circuit1]

[image: circuit2]

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need the net label ("VDD_IN" on top of the highlighted net) if you already have a hierarchical port connected. Maybe it creates confusion?

Comment: I solved the problem. The net name must be added in the parent component.

Comment: Ok good to know that in the end you still need the net label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. In this case, the net alias must be added in the parent component, which is connecting both child components.